# Oracle DBMS_LOB package OPEN procedure fails

Tags: oracle, hash, database

So I've got the function below. Works fine on my local oracle 11gR2. Doesn't work on client's 11gR2. Fails at dbms_lob.open. My question is 'why'. Any help welcome.

Here is what I've checked so far.
1. Oracle directory object permissions are the same in both places.
2. I've used dbms_output.put_line to check that all the right data is being selected.
3. client says file location *isn't* the problem.

BTW, basic purpose is just to calculate a simple sha1 (I know, I know, not a good hashing algo) for a file.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FC_Hash_Attachment (argAttachmentRSN int) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

v_hash RAW(2000);
b_file BFILE;
b_file_length BINARY_INTEGER;
dst_blob BLOB;
v_dosPath Attachment.dosPath%Type;
v_truncDosPath Attachment.dosPath%Type;
v_homeDir varchar2(50);
n_count int;

BEGIN
/* This function assumes the amanda_home directory object has been created.
   Further assumes the attachment is stored in the file system and not in the blob. */

/* Find the home directory so it can be stripped off the front of the dos path */
SELECT directory_path 
INTO v_homeDir
FROM all_directories 
WHERE UPPER(directory_name) = 'AMANDA_HOME';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_homeDir:' || v_homeDir);

/* get the dos path of the identified attachment */
SELECT dosPath
INTO v_dosPath 
FROM Attachment 
WHERE attachmentRSN = argAttachmentRSN;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_dosPath:' || v_dosPath);

/* Strip the home directory from the attachment save path */
v_truncDosPath := REPLACE(v_dosPath, v_homeDir);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_truncDosPath:' || v_truncDosPath);

/* create a temporary blob to store the attachment in */
DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(lob_loc => dst_blob, cache => true);



/* get the file into a bfile object */
b_file := BFILENAME('AMANDA_HOME', v_truncDosPath);


/* open the blob object as a read only */
DBMS_LOB.OPEN(b_file, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);


/* get the length of the blob object */
b_file_length := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(file_loc => b_file);


/* load the file */
DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(dst_blob, b_file, b_file_length);


/* hash the file using sha1 */
v_hash := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(src => dst_blob, typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);


/* close the file */
DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(file_loc => b_file);


RETURN RAWTOHEX(v_hash);    

EXCEPTION 
WHEN DBMS_LOB.INVALID_ARGVAL THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The argument is expecting a nonNULL, valid value but the argument value passed in is NULL, invalid, or out of range.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.ACCESS_ERROR THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You are trying to write too much data to the LOB: LOB size is limited to 4 gigabytes.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.NOEXIST_DIRECTORY THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The directory leading to the file does not exist.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.NOPRIV_DIRECTORY THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The user does not have the necessary access privileges on the directory or the file for the operation.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.INVALID_DIRECTORY THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The directory used for the current operation is not valid if being accessed for the first time, or if it has been modified by the DBA since the last access.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.OPERATION_FAILED THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The operation attempted on the file failed.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.UNOPENED_FILE THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The file is not open for the required operation to be performed.');
WHEN DBMS_LOB.OPEN_TOOMANY THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of open files has reached the maximum limit.');
--WHEN DBMS_LOB.NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EndofLob indicator for looping read operations. This is not a hard error.');
--WHEN DBMS_LOB.VALUE_ERROR THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PL/SQL error for invalid values to subprograms parameters.');


END;
```

The error they are getting is-

```
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation string failed string
The system could not find the specified path.
```

Comment: Don't you think it would help to tell us what the error is?

Comment: In addition to posting the error, what does "client says the file location isn't the problem" mean, exactly.  Are you saying that the client has verified that the operating system user that runs the Oracle database has appropriate privileges on the underlying operating system directory?  What operating system is your client using?

Comment: File opening exceptions are almost always down to either (1) incorrect path / file name, or (2) OS permissions on the directory.

Comment: OldProgrammer - yay, the error would probably be helpful. It is ORA-22288.

Comment: Justin Cave- OS is Windows Server 2008. I do believe the client has confirmed the user running the DB has file system permissions.

Comment: APC - could it be that I'm using UNC paths? Do I need to map the UNC to a drive letter and use the letter instead?